# How to get file creation dates for every files of a repertory ? (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing basic information about files in a csv.

For now i have file names and path for each file of my repertory.

I want the file creation date for each element of the repertory but I can get it for only one (i don't need timestamp format) :

```
import os
import csv

creadate = os.path.getctime(filename)

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(repertory):
        for filename in files:
            writer.writerow([filename + ';' + path + ';' + str(creadate)])
```

So I have obviously the same date all over the third row, and I can't figure out how to get it for all the files.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the date-getting logic in the loop, and use datetime to make it human readable.

```
import os
import csv
import datetime


repertory = '.'
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(repertory):
        for filename in files:
            create_date = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path, filename))
            create_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_date)
            writer.writerow([filename + ';' + path + ';' + str(create_date)])
```